# Combine INDIRECT with ADRESS function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have two Excel Sheets in the same workbook:
Sheet 1 (Name is AK):

```
      A      B     C
   --------------------
1  |  A2  |     |     |
   --------------------
2  |  20  |     |     |
   --------------------
```

Sheet 2 contains the following formula:
    `=INDIRECT("AK!" & ADDRESS(2;1;1;"TRUE";"AK"))`

Now I want to add this formula into the sheet dynamically via VBA and wrote this line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("q2").Formula = "=IF(A2<>"""",VLOOKUP(T2,INDIRECT(""AK!"" & ADDRESS(2,1,1,TRUE,""AK"")):INDIRECT(""AK!"" & ADDRESS(2,2,1,TRUE,""AK"")),2,0),"""")"
```

However I get the `#BEZUG` error (i am using Excel in German). What is wrong?

When I type the parts of the formula into a cell then I get the following results:

`=ADDRESS(2;1;1;TRUE;"AK")` results in `AK!$A$1` as expected.

However `=INDIRECT("AK!" & ADDRESS(2;1;1;"TRUE";"AK"))` results in `#BEZUG`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If `=ADDRESS(2;1;1;TRUE;"AK")` results in "AK1$A$2" shouldnt you remove "AK!" from the indirect?

Comment: This does not work, because `AK1$A$2` results in `A2`. And the `Indirect`-function should reference the `A2` in AK-sheet.

Comment: As the Darren just answered you should just use the address. In the address you indicate which sheet ("AK") should be used in the reference.
`=ADDRESS(2;1;1;TRUE;"AK")` results in cell A2 in sheet "AK".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting `Indirect`this way is the solution:

```
`=INDIRECT("AK!" & INDIRECT("AK!" & ADDRESS(2;1;1;"TRUE";"AK")))`
```

Answer (score 0):

`"AK!" & ADDRESS(2;1;1;"TRUE";"AK")` would give `AK!AK!$A$2` as the `Address` function already includes the sheet designation.

Use `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2;1;1;"TRUE";"AK")` instead.

Is `"TRUE"` correct?  Shouldn't it be 0 (R1C1 style) or 1 (A1 style)?